# One server which send data to one client. Using select() to have nonblocking I/O

Tags: c++, linux, select

I'm trying to develop a simple application where ONE Server sends data to ONE Client, using `select()` to stop client activity when there is nothing to read. 
I am able to send/read data but the `select()` system call seems to have not effect, since when the Server's writing operation has finished, the Client doesn't stop before the `select()` system call and continues to execute the operations which follow the `select()` (In this case a `printf`).

**This is the Server Code**

```
void initSocket()
{
    printf("socket initialized\n");
    sockFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockFd < 0)
    sockError("ERROR opening socket");

    bzero((char*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    portNum = 7550;
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(portNum);

    if (bind(sockFd, (struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
    sockError("ERROR on blinding");

    listen(sockFd, 5);
    cliLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    newsockFd = accept(sockFd, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &cliLen);
    if (newsockFd < 0)
    sockError("ERROR on accept");
    printf("Request received\n");
}

void sendGpsCoord(char* line)
{
    int n;

    n = write(newsockFd, line, sizeof(nmeaPOS));
    if (n < 0)
      printf("ERROR in writing socket");
}

void closeSocket()
{
    close(newsockFd);
    close(sockFd);
    printf("sockets closed\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("main started\n");
    initSocket();

    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL) {

        sendGpsCoord(&line);
    }

    closeSocket();
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine. It sends all data in the file and then exits.

---

The following is the Client code.
It receives and prints correctly all data, but when the server ends to send data, the client continues to print the string **I'm not blocking** in the while loop, while I expect it stop before the `select()` system call, since no data are anymore written on the socket and so the file descriptor `gpsSockRight` should not change anymore.

```
 fd_set readSetRight;
 struct sockaddr_in gpsServAddrLeft;
 int gpsServPortRight = 7550;
 int gpsSockRight;



 bool initGpsSocket()
 {
     bool ret = false;

     gpsSockRight = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (gpsSockRight < 0) {
         error("ERROR opening socket");
         ret = true;
     }

     gpsServRight = gethostbyname("192.168.2.91");

     bzero((char *) &gpsServAddrRight, sizeof(gpsServAddrRight));
     gpsServAddrRight.sin_family = AF_INET;

     bcopy((char *)gpsServRight->h_addr, 
           (char *)&gpsServAddrRight.sin_addr.s_addr,
           gpsServRight->h_length);

     gpsServAddrRight.sin_port = htons(gpsServPortRight);

     if (connect(gpsSockRight, (struct sockaddr *)   
         &gpsServAddrRight,sizeof(gpsServAddrRight)) < 0) {

         error("ERROR connecting");
         ret = true;
     }

     // To set the socket to be non blocking
     int on = 1;
     ioctl(gpsSockRight, FIONBIO, (char*)&on);

     return ret; 
}

void runGpsSocketRight()
{
    int n;
    string line;

    while(gRun) {  
        FD_ZERO(&readSetRight);
        FD_SET(gpsSockRight, &readSetRight);

        if (select(gpsSockRight +1 , &readSetRight, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
            error("select\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("I'm not blocking\n");

        if (FD_ISSET(gpsSockRight, &readSetRight)) {
            FD_CLR(gpsSockRight, &readSetRight);
            n = read(gpsSockRight, &line, sizeof(line));
            if (n < 0)
                error("ERROR reading from socket");
            else if (n == 0)
                ;
            else if (n > 0) {
                printf("Here is the line: %s\n", line);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you do not set `gRun` to `false` to exit the loop, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select returns when the socket is closed as an EOF flags the socket as ready-to-read. A subsequent read then returns size 0 showing you that the socket was closed on the other side.

In your code you check `if (n == 0)` and do nothing. You have to break out of the loop there because the closed socket will remain ready-to-read until closed.